# Problems with 'method' object is not subscriptable in pandas - Functions are not running

Tags: python, pandas

In my code I face a challenge: I always get the result that 'method' object is not subscriptable. The issue are the following functions in a more or less complex program:

```
def queryFruit(self,fruit):
        return self.result[self.result['FRUIT_TERM'].isin([fruit])]
    
def queryRelevance(self, fruit):
        onefruit = self.queryFruit(fruit)
        originparameters = pd.crosstab(onefruit['PARAMETER_NAME'], onefruit['COUNTRY_TERM']) >= 10
        validoriginparameters = originparameters.where(originparameters == True)
        validoriginparameters.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)
        validoriginparameters.dropna(axis=0, how='all', inplace=True)
        list1 = list(validoriginparameters.columns.values)
        list2 = list(validoriginparameters.index.values)
        return list1, list2
```

At the moment I can't see the forest for the trees... Does anyone have a tip?

Some few remarks/code regarding self.result:

```
def computeResult(self):
        self.result = self.getAnalyticalData
        log.debug('Query result successfully computed')
```

self.result marks a pd.DataFrame, containing 15 columns (one is: 'FRUIT_TERM').

Comment: Is `self.result` a method or an attribute in your class? If it is a method, can you add the code of the method?

Comment: I'll add it to the initial post. Please give me some few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add parenthesis to the method `self.getAnalyticalData` otherwise `self.result` is the method itself not the result of the method :

```
def computeResult(self):
        self.result = self.getAnalyticalData()
        log.debug('Query result successfully computed')
```